# flip order of passed arguments

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Is there a idiomatic / built-in way to flip the argument order that is passed to a function in Clojure?

As I do here with the definition of a helper function:

```
(defn flip [f & xs]
   (apply f (reverse xs)))


(vector 1 2)       ; [1 2]
(flip vector 1 2)  ; [2 1]
```

Comment: Yep, there is! You wrote it in your question. I'm not quite sure where this would be useful, though. Could you give a practical example?

Comment: I'm working with a 2d vector, say a grid with an x and an y axis. Then I have a function operating on that grid: this function operates on a continuous sequence of fields in the grid, sometimes vertically, sometime horizontally. In order to let the function not worry about the axes, I pass a either (partial vector) or (partial flip vector) to it. through that sub-function the function can operate on the grid in a more abstract way.

Comment: the same effect would happen if I'd swap the x and y axes in the grid when I need it. Mh, I'm not sure if that was explained well...

Comment: Could you post a code example of that in your question?

Comment: well, I tried to extract just the relevant parts. Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/antonharald/68bb0cbbebf964264270 Hope that clarifies the need for flipping. but maybe there are other ways..

Comment: That gist isn't syntactically correct. Could you please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question?

Comment: alright, I worked on the gist example. It's a valid program now. The functionality is lightly different now, I think the purpose should be more clear now.

Comment: @SamEstep it is quite useful for threading expressions where you want a short-circuit if it returns nil, and for code readability you'll need to flip some arguments depending on the order in which you call your middleware and the order of params in which said middleware wants to receive data.

ie. (some-> :transaction-id :body
                   api-response
                   (get-customer-info-by-id db-list)
                   #(sendmail body subject (:email %))
Notice sendmail looks unreadable whereas the rest of expressions have uniformity.

Answer (score 8):

I think it makes sense most times to create a flipped function that you use later, so the variation on your function would be this:

```
(defn flip [f]
  (fn [& xs]
    (apply f (reverse xs))))
```

Answer (score 6):

A flip function does exist in other functional languages, but it's easy enough to do in Clojure as well, and you've already done it!

There are [other](https://gist.github.com/micmarsh/bcbe19c9de8bb7a471bf) ways to do it as well.

And [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/7gCK7izwXBc) is a discussion about it from the Clojure mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use anonymous inline function to re-define the order of arguments.

```
(vector "a" "b")          ; ["a" "b"]  
(#(vector %2 %1) "a" "b") ; ["b" "a"]
```