# How to do divide function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am doing a `Divides?` function that takes as inputs a divisor x and a number n. The function should return true if x divides n and false otherwise.

at the moment this function works fine but I need to twist it a little bit more by adding an anonymous function with filter method, and also for the arguments have to be in the correct order `(x n)` rather than `(n x)`.

Any ideas would be appreciated:

**Divides?:**

```
(defn Divides? [x n]
 (zero? (mod n x)))
(println "Divides"( Divides? 2 10))
 //output : true
```

Comment: It's not quite clear, in your current function arguments are already `x n` rather than `n x`. Also, how exactly are you going to use it with filter?

Comment: There's nothing magic about the names `x` and `n`.Any distinct names will do. To get them in the right order, just swap them in the first line **or** the second. The filtering is a separate issue, which you have not made clear.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the order of `x` and `n`, so I have to figure out how to pass the arguments to `Divides` function in the correct order. hence I'm required to use the filter method but don't know how !

Comment: if you have the arguments in the right order, you might be able to use partial, but in the end, defining anon fn is just so easy: `#(Divides % 42)`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're  simply looking to flip the arguments of a function, in which case, [this answer may be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541142/flip-order-of-passed-arguments). Once you are able to flip the arguments which a function accepts, you shouldn't need to reimplement anything, but instead do something like:

```clj
(defn Divides? [x n]
 (zero? (mod n x)))

(defn flip [f]
  (fn [& xs]
    (apply f (reverse xs))))

((flip Divides?) 8 4)
```